# Why Yii module does not find system views?

Tags: php, yii

In app main config:

```
'errorHandler'=>array(
    // use 'site/error' action to display errors
    'errorAction'=>'site/default/error',
),
```

In  /protected/modules/site/controllers/ I have DefaultController.php with action error:

```
public function actionError()
{
    if($error=Yii::app()->errorHandler->error)
    {
        if(Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            echo $error['message'];
        else
            $this->render('error', $error);
    }
}
```

But if I have error, I see it:

`DefaultController cannot find the requested view "error". (/home/web/framework/web/CController.php:897)`

0 /home/web/framework/web/CController.php(800): CController->renderPartial('error', Array, true)
1 /home/web/apps/myapp/protected/modules/site/controllers/SiteController.php(67): CController->render('error', Array)
2 /home/web/framework/web/actions/CInlineAction.php(50): SiteController->actionError()
3 /home/web/framework/web/CController.php(309): CInlineAction->runWithParams(Array)
4 /home/web/framework/web/CController.php(287): CController->runAction(Object(CInlineAction))
5 /home/web/framework/web/CController.php(266): CController->runActionWithFilters(Object(CInlineAction), Array)
6 /home/web/framework/web/CWebApplication.php(283): CController->run('error')
7 /home/web/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(332): CWebApplication->runController('site/site/error')
8 /home/web/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(205): CErrorHandler->render('error', Array)
9 /home/web/framework/base/CErrorHandler.php(130): CErrorHandler->handleException(Object(CHttpException))
10 /home/web/framework/base/CApplication.php(713): CErrorHandler->handle(Object(CExceptionEvent))
11 [internal function]: CApplication->handleException(Object(CHttpException))

In Yii documentation:
CErrorHandler searches for the view file corresponding to a view in the following order:

1.WebRoot/themes/ThemeName/views/system: this is the system view directory under the currently active theme.

2.WebRoot/protected/views/system: this is the default system view directory for an application.

3.yii/framework/views: this is the standard system view directory provided by the Yii framework.

Why Yii not find views in yii/framework/views when using modules ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error handler takes as param error *action* not error *view*.

Also error message is clear, that `DefaultController` cannot find view.

When using modules, place views in module directory, not in main yii view folder. In your case  error view should be in `/protected/modules/site/views/default/error.php`, more generally: `/protected/modules/<moduleId>/views/<controllerId>/<viewName>.php`

To access root view, use `//`. From [docs about view name resolving](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#resolveViewFile-detail)

> Finds a view file based on its name.
>   The view name can be in one of the following formats:
>
> - absolute view within a module: the view name starts with a single slash '/'.
>     In this case, the view will be searched for under the currently active module's view path.
>     If there is no active module, the view will be searched for under the application's view path.
> - absolute view within the application: the view name starts with double slashes '//'.
>     In this case, the view will be searched for under the application's view path.
>     This syntax has been available since version 1.1.3.
> - aliased view: the view name contains dots and refers to a path alias.
>     The view file is determined by calling [YiiBase::getPathOfAlias()](/doc/api/1.1/YiiBase#getPathOfAlias). Note that aliased views
>     cannot be themed because they can refer to a view file located at arbitrary places.
> - relative view: otherwise. Relative views will be searched for under the currently active
>     controller's view path.
>
> For absolute view and relative view, the corresponding view file is a PHP file
>   whose name is the same as the view name. The file is located under a specified directory.
>   This method will call [CApplication::findLocalizedFile](/doc/api/1.1/CApplication#findLocalizedFile) to search for a localized file, if any.

**NOTE**: This applies only to *controller* views.

Comment: I know it and it works. But I'm interested why the item 3 in my question (yii/framework/views) not working when using module ?

Comment: To access view in base folder regardless of being in module or not, start name with double slash `//`