# yii module layouts customize

Tags: php, layout, yii, module

In yii,I create a module called "admin" and I want to set the module to use the layouts I customized other than the defalult.so I seach some posts and it worked!
 this is the post I read:

http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/24767-module-layout/

after i configured my app as the post,my app worked very well.but now I have some quetions:

1. **the layoutPath**
   the post said configure
   `$this->layoutPath = Yii::getPathOfAlias('administration.views.layouts');`
   the layoutPah variable confuse me very much,it seems this var not be defined in any class.so why it can be called by `$this`?
2. **`/layouts/main`**
   what is the difference between `/layouts/main` and `//layouts/main`
   when use `//layouts/main` it will not worked,the app still call the default main layout not mine?
3. **overwriting**
   the post also said the `public $layout='//layouts/column1';` in controller overwriting the 
   value set in the `init()` method for the module controller 。
   is this tru?

Comment: For #2 check my similar answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17467209/why-yii-module-does-not-find-system-views/17467760#17467760

Comment: thank you ver much!this solved my question #2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The layoutPath**
   The LayoutPath is defined in `CWebApplication` see [details in the wiki](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CWebApplication#layoutPath-detail)
   So you can se it by using:
   `Yii::app()->layoutPath= Yii::getPathOfAlias('administration.views.layouts');`
2. Answered by PeterM
3. overwriting
   See the description of the [CController layout attribute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#layout-detail):

   > The name of the layout to be applied to this controller's views. Defaults to null, meaning the application layout is used. If it is false, no layout will be applied. The module layout will be used if the controller belongs to a module and this layout property is null.

So you need to set it to null and the module layout will be used.
Note: In any action of your controller you can set the layout to null `$this->layout=null;` so the layout will be null only in this action and not in the others!

Comment: If the answer solves your problem you should mark it as solved by ticking the box!

Comment: Yeah you'v done it right! It's usefull so people who have the same problem will know that the answer could resolve their problems (and you and I are earning some points ^^ )

Answer (score 0):

you can put the following code in your controller.

```
public function init()
{
    Yii::$app->setLayoutPath($this->module->getBasePath().'/views/layout');
}
```

or you can put the following code in your module bootstrap class

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    Yii::$app->setLayoutPath($this->getBasePath().'/views/layout');
}
```